# how to localize the dynamic content in iphone?

Tags: iphone, internationalization

Hi am able to localize the static content like labels,buttons,images e.t.c.But when the content is dynamic,for example...strings retrived from web services.how to localize such kind of content,if it is possible please lemme know thx in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the data is Dynamic ,you can't use String file because one can know the localized word for other words.

So ,its better to add one more Field in web service response which is having the localized word according to localization. Just parse it & make the dynamic localized app.

I had done in this way for an Arabic language.It works well. Hope that could solve your problem unto some extent.

Comment: if that is the case the person who is creating the  web service should take care of the localization right?

Comment: Yes....that is. Even you can also do the same thing.Just generate a XML file and make entry in it & upload that XML file on server.Then just parse it @ ur side.

Answer (score 3):

The general idea is to add localization parameter (like locale=es) in the web service request and the server will send the localized version of the content. That means you need to add localization support in server too.